# Workaround for IE 11 flexbox text wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

In the first div below, note that the outer div is `flex-direction:row`, and the inner div is `flex-direction:column`.  I believe this particular arrangement causes the text in the P tag to not wrap in IE 11.

In the second div, the outer div is `flex-direction:column` and the inner div is `flex-direction:row` and it works fine in all browsers.

My layout is highly dependent on the outer div being `flex-direction:row`.  My question is, is their any way I can work around this issue by say, wrapping the text in some other element?  I have tried setting display:block,inline, etc and it does not work.

**Div 1:**

```
<div style="background-color:gray;display:flex;flex-direction:row;">
    <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;">
        <p>THIS TEXT DOES NOT WRAP IN IE 11. WORKS IN CHROME, EDGE.  Fed Chair Janet Yellen could clear the air next week, sounding more concrete on whether the central bank will squeeze in a rate hike or two this year, but more likely she won't. Yellen is scheduled to speak next Friday in Jackson Hole, Wyoming, and for markets that has been the most important event on the calendar this month. It also comes after the debate in markets heated up about whether the Fed could actually raise rates in September, or will wait until the end of the year or even later. I think she's going to play her cards very close to the vest. I don't think she can signal a September hike," said Diane Swonk, CEO of DS Economics. Swonk said three inflation reports and the August employment report will be released after the Aug. 26 speech and before the Sept. 20 Fed meeting. "She's got to leave her options open." But Swonk said the Fed is caught in a difficult spot, and there are good reasons why it would want to ease sooner even though it's unlikely. "It's the Fed's conundrum. ... The markets are pricing in easing infinity. If they raise rates, they could destabilize the markets. If they don't raise rates, they're feeding a bubble. It's a hard place to be in," she said. Barclays' chief U.S. economist, Michael Gapen, is among a minority on Wall Street who believe the Fed could raise rates in September. "I hope she steps up and gives an interesting speech. Don't give me this blah-dity blah. The markets need to hear from her. She's lost some credibility with investors. There are many market participants that believe she will never see sufficient data to make her move," he said </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Div 2**

```
<div style="background-color:lightblue;display:flex;flex-direction:column;">
    <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;">
        <p>THIS TEXT WRAPS CORRECTLY IN IE 11, CHROME, EDGE. Fed Chair Janet Yellen could clear the air next week, sounding more concrete on whether the central bank will squeeze in a rate hike or two this year, but more likely she won't. Yellen is scheduled to speak next Friday in Jackson Hole, Wyoming, and for markets that has been the most important event on the calendar this month. It also comes after the debate in markets heated up about whether the Fed could actually raise rates in September, or will wait until the end of the year or even later. I think she's going to play her cards very close to the vest. I don't think she can signal a September hike," said Diane Swonk, CEO of DS Economics. Swonk said three inflation reports and the August employment report will be released after the Aug. 26 speech and before the Sept. 20 Fed meeting. "She's got to leave her options open." But Swonk said the Fed is caught in a difficult spot, and there are good reasons why it would want to ease sooner even though it's unlikely. "It's the Fed's conundrum. ... The markets are pricing in easing infinity. If they raise rates, they could destabilize the markets. If they don't raise rates, they're feeding a bubble. It's a hard place to be in," she said. Barclays' chief U.S. economist, Michael Gapen, is among a minority on Wall Street who believe the Fed could raise rates in September. "I hope she steps up and gives an interesting speech. Don't give me this blah-dity blah. The markets need to hear from her. She's lost some credibility with investors. There are many market participants that believe she will never see sufficient data to make her move," he said </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `width: 100%` to the nested div.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!  Please add this as answer.

Comment: I've posted a complete answer in the dupe.